# Excel file does not open in browser

Tags: c#, excel, aspose

I am using aspose to find specific text and highlight it and open that excel file in browser.
Problem is it find and highlight and excel file get downloaded, which i dont want i want to show the contents of excel in browser.
For pdf this works perfectly fine, opens up in browser

```
PDF code -
    if (docBytes != null)
                {
                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-length", docBytes.Length.ToString());
                    Response.BinaryWrite(docBytes);

                }
```

Here is my code - (excel) - Does not open excel in browser

```
 using (MemoryStream docStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                workbook.Save(docStream, Aspose.Cells.SaveFormat.Xlsx);
                docBytes = docStream.ToArray();

            }

            if (docBytes != null)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";               
                Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
                        "attachment; filename=" + "yourExcelFileName.xlsx");               
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", docBytes.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(docBytes);
                Response.End();

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines.

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
    "attachment; filename=" + "yourExcelFileName.xlsx");
```

The "attachment" part tells the browser that this file should be downloaded and not displayed in the browser.

Remove that and it should work (in browser that can host Excel at least, so Internet Explorer and possibly Edge).

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=yourExcelFileName.xlsx");
```

You can read about the `attachment` parameter over on MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#Syntax

Comment: How to make it work in chrome ? In chrome it simply downloads the file ? in IE it prompts with option of Open/Save/SaveAs instead of showing in browser

Comment: I'm pretty sure Chrome won't let you host Excel in it. Possibly it could be done with a plugin of some sort but I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: Ok. How about IE ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try the line instead if it makes any difference:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition",
                        "inline; filename=" + "yourExcelFileName.xlsx");
```

Comment: behaves same..does not open in chrome..downloads it and in IE it prompts with option of Open/Save/SaveAs instead of showing in browser

Comment: To make certain file types OPEN into chrome. You have to download the file type once, then right after that download, look at the status bar at the bottom of the browser. Click the arrow next to that file and choose "always open files of this type". DONE.  You will have to do it just once for various files such Excel, Excel, Word files, etc.